# Почему не работает код на с# для вывода бинарного ресурса?

Tags: c#, вывод, ресурсы

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\1\Desktop\123\smth.cs", WindowsFormsApp12.Properties.Resources.smth);
```

Ошибка : resources не содержит определения для smth (подчеркивает smth)

Суть : по нажатию на кнопку нужно вывести в папку 123 на рабочем столе файл smth.cs из ресурсов

Comment: Почему этот код должен работать?

Comment: потому что я его нашел на стаке, и по идее он должен работать :)

Comment: Попробуйте разобраться в вопросе и понять, что ваш код делает. Мне кажется, вы быстро сами разберетесь в том, где тут проблема.

Comment: `smth` - это сокращение англ.слова `something`, т.е. дано для примера. Вместо этого нужно подставлять реальное название вашего ресурса. `smth.cs` - странный выбор для названия бинарного файла, т.к. это расширение зарегистрировано за текстовыми файлами кода написанного на C#. Короче, у вас написана полная дичь, и потому ничего не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Класс `Properties.Resources` содержит автосгенерированный код для доступа к ресурсам проекта, каждому файлу ресурса соответствует свойство в этом классе. Для того, чтобы там появился "smth", нужно добавить одноименный ресурс в свойствах проекта на вкладке "Ресурсы".

Answer (score -1):

Суть ответа заключается в том, что я зря начал искать окольные пути вывода файлов, бинарные то или обычные файлы, их нужно под одну гребенку выводить пример кода https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tue13zNKzDs 
Там конечно ничего не объясняется , но недолго поломав голову вы поймете суть.